# Test cases for UVA 822

Tags: java, queue

I need more test cases for my code, it is displaying the correct answers however UVa still does not accept it.

The instruction is, 
As requests are received, they are classified according to a predetermined list of topics. Each member of the support staff has responsibility for one or more of these topics and each topic has one or more support personnel assigned to it. Because staff members have different levels of expertise, each staff member has a prioritized list of topics that he or she can handle. Staff personnel are not permitted to handle requests outside their specified areas.

As staff members become available, they select from the pool of waiting requests according to their priority list of topics. All requests arriving at time t are available for allocation at time t. If two staff members are simultaneously available, scheduling preference is given to the one whose most recent job was scheduled earliest. If there is still a tie, scheduling preference is given to the person whose id number appears earlier in the input list of staff people. At the opening of business, all personnel are available to handle requests.

Input consists of a number of scenarios. Each scenario begins with the number of request topics, a positive integer no larger than 20. This is followed by a description of each topic. Each description consists of five integer values: a unique topic identifier, the number of requests for that topic, the elapsed time before the first request for that topic is received, the time needed to service a request, and the time between successive requests. All but the third of these values are positive integers; the elapsed time until the first request could be zero. Following this, the number of personnel is given. This will be a positive integer not to exceed 5. Finally, a description of each person is given in the form of three or more positive integer values: a unique identifying number for the person, the number of topics covered by this person, and a list of the topic identifiers arranged from highest priority to lowest priority for that person. A zero follows the last scenario.

The output is the sum of total minutes for each scenario.

Here is an example run of my program:
Input:

```
3
128 20 0 5 10
134 25 5 6 7
153 30 10 4 5
4
10 2 128 134
11 1 134
12 2 128 153
13 1 153
1
128 5 0 1 10
1
11 1 128
0
```

Output:

```
Scenario 1: All requests are serviced within 195 minutes.
Scenario 2: All requests are serviced within 41 minutes.
```

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class RequestSet{//Structure for RequestSets
            private int id;
            private int qty;
            private int firstReq;
            private int timeReq;
            private int nextReq;
            private int sucReq;
            private int initialized;

            public RequestSet(int id,int qty,int firstReq,int timeReq,int nextReq){
                this.id=id;
                this.qty=qty;
                this.firstReq=firstReq;
                this.timeReq=timeReq;
                this.nextReq=nextReq;
                sucReq=nextReq;
                initialized=0;
            }

            public void decReq(){//Decreases the time attributes
                if(firstReq>1)
                    firstReq-=1;
                else if((nextReq!=1) && (firstReq==0 || firstReq==1))
                    nextReq-=1;
            }

            public int getInitial(){//Determines if the Request set has already enqueued its first element
                return initialized;
            }

            public void setInitial(){
                initialized=1;
            }

            public void decQty(){//Decreases the requests qty of the Request set(When the set enqueues a request to the spool)
                qty--;
            }

            public void restoreReq(){//Replenishes the time remaining until the next Request
                nextReq=sucReq;
            }

            public int getID(){
                return id;
            }

            public int getQty(){
                return qty;
            }

            public int getFReq(){
                return firstReq;
            }

            public int getTimeReq(){
                return timeReq;
            }

            public int getNReq(){
                return nextReq;
            }
        }//End of Class "Request Set"

        class Request{//Structure for a Request

            private int topicID;
            private int minsNeeded;

            public Request(int id, int mins){
                topicID = id;
                minsNeeded = mins;
            }

            public int getMins(){
                return minsNeeded;
            }

            public int getId(){
                return topicID;
            }
        }//End of Class "Request"

        class Server{//Structure for Agents

            private int id;
            private int topicsQty;
            private ArrayList<Integer> specialty;
            private int available;
            private int recentJobAgo;
            private int occTil;
            private int listStanding;

            public Server(int id, int qty, int stand){
                this.id=id;
                topicsQty=qty;
                available=1;
                specialty = new ArrayList();
                occTil=0;
                listStanding=stand;
            }

            public Server(){

            }

            public int getOcc(){
                return occTil;
            }

            public int getPosition(){//Returns the position of the agent in the input list(Agent which was inputted first)
                return listStanding;
            }

            public int getRecJ(){//Return the time elapsed after the most recent job
                return recentJobAgo;
            }


            public void display(){
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<topicsQty;i++){
                    System.out.printf("%d ",specialty.get(i));
                }
            }

            public void progress(){
                if(available==1)//if agent is available, the time elapsed after the most recent job is incremented
                    recentJobAgo+=1;
                else if(available==0 && (occTil==1 || occTil==0)){//case wherein an agent finishes a request. "occTil==0"-occupied til 0 mins
                    available=1;
                    occTil=0;
                }
                else//case where in the agent's still occupied, so we decrease the "Occupied Until" attribute
                    occTil--;
            }

            public int isAvailable(){
                return available;
            }

            public void occupy(int time){//Agent begins servicing a request
                if(time>0){
                    available=0;
                    recentJobAgo=0;
                    occTil=time;
                }
            }

            public void doneReq(){
                available=1;
            }

            public void learnTopics(int topicID){//Gets the input from the 3rd to the nth input, for agents. Priority topics.
                int i;
                specialty.add(topicID);
            }

            public int canDo(int id, int i){//returns 1 if the topicID is in the agent's ArrayList of topic names
                int result=0;
                //for(i=0;i<topicsQty;i++){
                if(i<specialty.size())
                    if(id==specialty.get(i) && available==1){
                        result=1;
                    }
                //}
                return result;
            }
        }//End of Class "Server"

        int topics, servers, i, result, check, rounds=0, minute;
        String dump;
        ArrayList<Integer> minutes;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j, k=0;
        int topicID, noReqs, bFirst, timeReq, betReqs, set;
        //topicID,# of Requests, time before the 1st request, time requirement to process a request, succeeding time between requests
        int agentID, lrndTopics, aTopic;
        //agentID, # of priority topics, used to hold a topicID
        ArrayList<RequestSet> requests;
        Server[] agent;//Could have also been an arraylist
        Server temp;//for sorting the agents
        String input;
        Queue<Request> spool = new LinkedList<>();
        minutes=new ArrayList();//Used to hold several results. i.e. if the user inputs several scenarios

        int firstInput=sc.nextInt();

        if(firstInput!=0){
        do{
            if(k==0)
            {
                topics=firstInput;
            }
            else
            {
                topics=rounds;
            }
            dump=sc.nextLine();//Filters out "Enter"/"NextLine"

            requests = new ArrayList();
            for(i=0; i<topics; i++)
            {
//                input=sc.nextLine();//Gets a string input containing 5 numbers
//                StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input);
//                topicID=Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());//Gets the first number from the input
//                noReqs=Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());//Gets the 2nd
//                bFirst=Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());//3rd
//                timeReq=Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());//4th
//                betReqs=Integer.parseInt((String)strToken.nextElement());//5th
//                requests.add(new RequestSet(topicID,noReqs,bFirst,timeReq,betReqs));//Adds the request topic into the RequestSet array
                //input=sc.nextLine();//Gets a string input containing 5 numbers
                //StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input);
                topicID=sc.nextInt();//Gets the first number from the input
                noReqs=sc.nextInt();//Gets the 2nd
                bFirst=sc.nextInt();//3rd
                timeReq=sc.nextInt();//4th
                betReqs=sc.nextInt();//5th
                requests.add(new RequestSet(topicID,noReqs,bFirst,timeReq,betReqs));//Adds the request topic into the RequestSet array

            }
            servers=sc.nextInt();//Gets the number of Agents

            dump=sc.nextLine();//Filters out "Enter"/"NextLine"

            agent = new Server[servers];//Creates an array of agents
            for(i=0; i<servers; i++)
            {
//                input=sc.nextLine();//Accepts a line of input
//                StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input);
                //System.out.println("agent section");
                agentID=sc.nextInt();//Gets the first input
                lrndTopics=sc.nextInt();//Gets the 2nd input
                agent[i] = new Server(agentID, lrndTopics,i);//Creates an agent in the array

                for(j=0;j<lrndTopics; j++)//Gets the priority list of topics, loops n times based on the 2nd input
                {
                    aTopic=sc.nextInt();//Gets the 3rd input until the nth input
                    agent[i].learnTopics(aTopic);//calls a function that adds the topic into the agent's priority list.
                }
            }//Gets inputs for the agent set

            set=0;//prevents the "minute" variable from increasing at the beginning
            minute=0;
            //Request processing section

            //PROCESSING PART
            do{
                if(set==1)
                    minute++;


                for(i=0;i<topics;i++)//Checks if a request set is able to add a request into the Queue
                {
                    if((requests.get(i).getFReq()==0 || requests.get(i).getFReq()==1) && requests.get(i).getInitial()==0)
                    {
                        spool.add(new Request(requests.get(i).getID(),requests.get(i).getTimeReq()));
                        requests.get(i).decQty();
                        requests.get(i).restoreReq();
                        requests.get(i).setInitial();
                    }
                    else if(requests.get(i).getInitial()==1 && (requests.get(i).getNReq()==1)  && requests.get(i).getQty()>0)
                    {
                        spool.add(new Request(requests.get(i).getID(),requests.get(i).getTimeReq()));
                        requests.get(i).decQty();
                        requests.get(i).restoreReq();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        requests.get(i).decReq();
                    }
                }

                //Sorts the agents according to their idle time. Most idle places first
//                for(i=0;i< (servers-1);i++)
//                {
//                    for(j=0;j< servers-i-1;j++)
//                        if(agent[j].getRecJ()<agent[j+1].getRecJ())
//                        {
//                            temp=agent[j];
//                            agent[j]=agent[j+1];
//                            agent[j+1]=temp;
//                        }
//                }



                //Swaps agents when they have equal idle time. The agent that was inputted first places first
                for(i=0;i< servers-1;i++)
                {
                        if(agent[i].getRecJ()==agent[i+1].getRecJ()){
                            if(agent[i].getPosition()>agent[i+1].getPosition()){
                                temp=agent[i];
                                agent[i]=agent[i+1];
                                agent[i+1]=temp;
                            }
                        }
                }

                //Decreases all the time attributes of all the agents
                for(i=0;i<servers;i++)
                {
                    agent[i].progress();
                }




                //Checks all agents if they're qualified to service a topic
                for(j=0;j<topics;j++)
                {
                    for(i=0;i<servers;i++)
                    {
                        if(spool.peek()!=null)
                        {
                                if(agent[i].canDo(spool.peek().getId(),j)==1)
                                {
                                    agent[i].occupy(spool.peek().getMins());
                                    spool.remove();
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }

                set=1;
                check=0;
                result=0;

                //Checks all the requests sets' number of remaining topics
                for(j=0;j<topics;j++)
                {
                    if(requests.get(j).getQty()!=0)
                        check=1;
                }
                //Checks if all the agents are occupied
                for(i=0;i<servers;i++)
                {
                    if(agent[i].isAvailable()==0)
                        result=1;
                }

                if(check==0 && result==1)//if all request sets are empty, check if an agent is still servicing a topic
                    check=1;


//                System.out.println(requests.get(0).getQty()+" QTY");
//                System.out.println(agent[0].getOcc()+" OCCTIL");
            }while(check==1);//End of PROCESSING PART


            minutes.add(minute);//Adds the result into the results array
            rounds=sc.nextInt();//If '0' is inputted, the program ends, otherwise, it will be stored into the "topics" variable
            if(rounds!=0)
                k++;

            for(i=topics-1;i>=0;i--)//Removes all the request sets from the requests array, to prepare for a next scenario
                requests.remove(i);


        }while(rounds!=0);      
        }
        //Displays all the results
        for(i=0;i<minutes.size();i++)
            System.out.println("Scenario "+(i+1)+": All requests are serviced within "+minutes.get(i)+" minutes.");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The website [uDebug](http://www.udebug.com/UVa/822), linked on the main UVaOnline Judge website, will generate random valid input data for questions when available.

Below are some additional test cases in case the website goes down.

```
2
1 91 89 79 50
2 92 49 60 19
4
1 1 2
2 2 1 2
3 2 1 2
4 2 1 2
15
1 68 36 23 2
2 9 6 19 60
3 67 10 6 49
4 49 44 23 66
5 81 8 18 35
6 99 85 85 75
7 94 75 94 96
8 29 7 67 28
9 100 95 11 89
10 29 16 10 29
11 32 55 10 15
12 70 48 4 84
13 100 36 63 73
14 42 93 28 47
15 100 35 2 73
3
1 13 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14
2 10 2 3 4 5 9 10 11 12 14 15
3 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 13 14 15
5
1 41 69 57 29
2 41 76 99 22
3 12 58 30 38
4 3 63 31 52
5 7 58 82 81
5
1 3 1 2 3
2 4 1 3 4 5
3 3 1 2 4
4 2 2 4
5 4 1 2 3 5
12
1 38 19 44 83
2 9 51 58 43
3 1 3 86 42
4 1 67 31 63
5 74 23 82 49
6 7 65 69 76
7 91 33 24 75
8 5 1 44 22
9 81 21 8 39
10 11 20 43 17
11 43 92 17 29
12 48 87 52 48
5
1 9 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10
2 6 5 6 9 10 11 12
3 10 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
4 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
5 8 3 4 5 6 8 9 11 12
1
1 33 11 23 34
3
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
5
1 11 94 25 10
2 78 37 50 46
3 19 20 52 28
4 89 78 46 13
5 70 73 29 96
4
1 4 1 3 4 5
2 4 1 2 3 4
3 4 2 3 4 5
4 2 1 2
10
1 42 54 54 70
2 11 28 75 63
3 81 47 39 23
4 84 66 89 89
5 28 43 20 45
6 25 27 44 90
7 9 78 50 29
8 19 36 43 50
9 11 87 79 97
10 28 7 77 6
1
1 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
17
1 96 73 21 85
2 5 33 5 26
3 27 89 74 72
4 4 10 24 17
5 73 67 61 54
6 71 34 65 52
7 59 56 11 61
8 84 84 40 99
9 37 9 2 60
10 81 31 50 58
11 40 1 5 24
12 33 67 25 28
13 41 99 16 38
14 93 4 26 81
15 86 72 60 88
16 10 9 25 99
17 88 63 51 79
3
1 12 1 3 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16
2 8 2 3 5 7 8 10 11 15
3 11 1 2 4 5 6 8 9 12 13 14 17
15
1 42 22 49 10
2 81 48 24 89
3 77 21 1 68
4 37 12 57 86
5 90 88 50 99
6 58 39 52 20
7 58 54 9 100
8 32 8 4 71
9 92 78 39 4
10 81 52 94 62
11 84 16 50 46
12 57 53 27 58
13 100 9 67 28
14 69 26 47 70
15 77 46 40 55
3
1 10 1 2 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 15
2 9 1 2 3 4 5 8 11 12 14
3 7 1 3 4 7 9 10 11
14
1 64 92 67 87
2 67 48 5 47
3 83 18 98 13
4 53 86 74 62
5 64 49 85 18
6 13 5 48 56
7 66 16 73 54
8 58 42 33 19
9 46 67 14 100
10 34 98 21 70
11 84 55 47 71
12 38 77 52 20
13 43 100 55 88
14 8 31 70 2
3
1 5 2 4 5 7 14
2 9 1 3 4 6 7 9 10 11 12
3 7 2 5 7 8 9 11 13
8
1 48 59 53 54
2 67 97 8 25
3 14 40 99 50
4 15 56 50 40
5 32 76 1 81
6 76 68 79 42
7 69 66 58 7
8 42 7 50 89
2
1 6 1 2 3 5 6 8
2 5 4 5 6 7 8
19
1 37 30 79 84
2 33 56 33 2
3 82 41 59 84
4 49 38 6 5
5 80 74 74 67
6 50 100 35 73
7 92 86 64 83
8 82 15 36 98
9 67 18 82 66
10 49 68 32 14
11 47 52 63 42
12 39 54 53 21
13 3 17 70 79
14 90 70 51 56
15 12 67 88 14
16 40 29 71 23
17 17 99 62 52
18 39 56 9 46
19 91 22 48 71
2
1 11 2 3 4 6 8 12 13 15 16 17 19
2 15 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18
3
1 5 18 79 55
2 5 91 80 100
3 77 46 3 80
2
1 3 1 2 3
2 3 1 2 3
16
1 29 4 84 43
2 52 70 98 22
3 19 21 39 88
4 48 58 60 94
5 25 21 26 8
6 20 61 22 33
7 60 73 39 43
8 69 55 76 27
9 33 20 50 11
10 86 17 32 99
11 16 4 39 70
12 58 55 6 51
13 64 9 29 32
14 45 63 89 3
15 5 7 76 79
16 14 75 14 3
3
1 10 1 4 5 7 10 11 12 13 14 16
2 10 1 2 3 4 6 8 9 14 15 16
3 9 1 3 4 9 10 11 12 14 15
9
1 23 53 87 17
2 12 77 53 8
3 48 36 73 46
4 53 64 12 48
5 83 39 10 28
6 33 23 92 52
7 44 0 68 53
8 88 89 93 20
9 39 31 71 79
3
1 7 1 2 3 4 6 7 8
2 6 1 3 6 7 8 9
3 8 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
7
1 54 52 80 90
2 54 42 16 40
3 86 77 68 74
4 41 66 87 23
5 80 58 71 79
6 64 4 39 91
7 26 54 87 73
1
1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
7
1 67 40 98 97
2 16 53 36 26
3 99 26 73 12
4 75 64 66 46
5 44 41 12 10
6 87 68 30 19
7 23 76 67 83
4
1 4 3 4 6 7
2 6 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 4 1 3 4 7
4 3 1 2 4
3
1 4 91 75 93
2 42 52 48 28
3 28 9 20 97
4
1 2 1 3
2 3 1 2 3
3 1 1
4 1 2
5
1 34 62 29 35
2 80 92 77 61
3 13 62 9 97
4 39 62 3 1
5 5 2 73 69
4
1 1 3
2 5 1 2 3 4 5
3 4 2 3 4 5
4 4 2 3 4 5
12
1 89 93 49 57
2 58 40 12 89
3 37 100 98 31
4 53 65 92 19
5 14 47 96 81
6 54 41 11 73
7 77 53 27 10
8 71 85 91 63
9 79 100 7 91
10 1 33 15 18
11 83 98 20 13
12 44 73 64 63
4
1 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11
2 7 4 5 6 8 9 11 12
3 9 1 2 3 5 6 9 10 11 12
4 8 1 2 4 5 9 10 11 12
17
1 63 3 80 69
2 35 6 23 50
3 12 81 13 46
4 21 80 18 27
5 88 28 51 40
6 2 95 37 79
7 25 42 47 62
8 15 95 20 47
9 52 89 64 51
10 31 29 88 86
11 30 44 90 52
12 50 99 97 59
13 78 66 99 48
14 48 49 85 35
15 30 25 92 31
16 13 76 37 63
17 85 68 73 100
2
1 12 1 4 5 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 16 17
2 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 12 13 14 15 17
12
1 66 47 26 25
2 44 19 1 80
3 95 5 33 51
4 57 56 98 41
5 92 25 83 71
6 27 46 48 18
7 19 71 77 78
8 89 80 37 12
9 93 30 81 14
10 83 11 95 33
11 72 38 11 80
12 31 14 20 61
4
1 9 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 11 12
2 9 1 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12
3 9 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
4 6 1 2 4 6 7 12
1
1 4 65 22 66
5
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
5 1 1
2
1 56 66 32 11
2 37 2 92 41
2
1 2 1 2
2 1 1
12
1 12 5 100 14
2 91 41 85 38
3 11 22 13 20
4 11 32 100 14
5 49 84 35 55
6 44 44 19 71
7 98 38 14 50
8 58 92 3 45
9 43 0 2 54
10 57 22 50 86
11 28 95 70 14
12 75 94 13 69
4
1 10 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 12
2 5 2 3 6 7 8
3 7 2 3 5 8 9 10 11
4 6 1 4 7 9 10 11
10
1 22 62 94 6
2 43 39 85 23
3 1 66 37 23
4 32 49 46 86
5 95 1 37 2
6 16 40 14 49
7 81 53 54 28
8 60 68 73 54
9 41 74 76 19
10 87 27 34 12
1
1 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
7
1 5 21 21 12
2 70 11 73 84
3 54 71 34 95
4 69 64 8 25
5 32 68 23 96
6 33 16 92 62
7 28 0 57 33
5
1 6 1 2 3 4 5 7
2 6 1 2 3 5 6 7
3 6 1 2 3 4 6 7
4 4 3 5 6 7
5 4 2 3 6 7
1
1 19 16 20 26
4
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
12
1 56 15 1 99
2 57 5 61 75
3 9 87 12 79
4 2 26 72 10
5 68 16 31 50
6 55 74 98 50
7 93 84 91 47
8 58 11 50 60
9 77 99 12 50
10 3 86 77 73
11 49 56 17 40
12 37 45 23 88
3
1 5 2 3 6 7 8
2 9 1 2 4 5 8 9 10 11 12
3 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12
10
1 14 2 34 50
2 22 21 34 51
3 25 7 42 2
4 38 57 96 86
5 49 16 98 48
6 33 72 33 97
7 60 45 61 27
8 10 37 88 9
9 24 93 23 22
10 9 94 26 56
2
1 6 3 4 6 7 8 9
2 7 1 2 3 4 5 7 10
1
1 4 90 43 63
1
1 1 1
7
1 34 92 40 29
2 96 58 56 64
3 36 43 35 10
4 13 5 52 46
5 51 33 85 92
6 73 10 49 79
7 11 77 69 75
1
1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1
1 24 62 77 40
5
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 1 1
5 1 1
10
1 63 75 7 79
2 92 81 66 52
3 86 59 66 32
4 58 83 100 30
5 97 93 53 72
6 38 27 40 59
7 32 16 45 79
8 4 99 3 25
9 13 1 1 62
10 1 78 64 18
4
1 8 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 9 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10
3 9 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
4 5 2 3 6 8 10
5
1 5 45 47 17
2 74 94 3 73
3 4 29 57 96
4 45 95 73 54
5 40 13 41 91
5
1 4 1 3 4 5
2 4 1 2 4 5
3 4 1 2 3 5
4 3 1 3 5
5 4 2 3 4 5
8
1 82 35 25 8
2 88 57 83 9
3 32 2 44 95
4 81 35 1 62
5 2 95 25 36
6 29 17 2 68
7 10 39 85 23
8 51 1 31 92
2
1 7 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 5 1 4 6 7 8
7
1 17 94 29 10
2 12 85 90 3
3 53 25 90 24
4 1 46 52 69
5 2 51 18 15
6 58 29 88 61
7 33 85 43 18
5
1 4 2 5 6 7
2 4 1 3 6 7
3 4 1 2 3 7
4 6 1 3 4 5 6 7
5 5 2 3 4 6 7
11
1 45 95 49 34
2 85 39 56 87
3 87 50 62 57
4 9 13 35 14
5 67 33 98 27
6 83 46 36 14
7 4 78 37 36
8 11 43 35 78
9 73 10 49 35
10 13 43 49 56
11 28 98 82 63
1
1 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
4
1 29 79 25 47
2 100 32 25 75
3 1 94 38 61
4 2 96 10 50
2
1 3 1 2 4
2 3 1 2 3
17
1 79 20 54 53
2 91 29 33 78
3 20 64 52 70
4 45 80 70 14
5 67 27 14 59
6 59 56 77 72
7 12 43 94 50
8 26 40 36 22
9 66 86 57 89
10 10 44 34 89
11 50 30 50 37
12 78 9 53 19
13 38 75 16 66
14 45 35 73 44
15 92 40 27 19
16 2 28 28 62
17 72 95 73 84
3
1 10 2 4 6 9 10 11 12 15 16 17
2 14 1 2 3 4 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17
3 11 2 3 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 15 17
2
1 36 76 13 33
2 7 6 40 12
1
1 2 1 2
20
1 75 37 44 70
2 95 65 10 33
3 34 48 68 50
4 94 16 41 81
5 60 63 68 73
6 37 49 65 31
7 63 7 89 77
8 51 13 89 30
9 68 45 13 84
10 24 80 57 75
11 9 95 6 77
12 23 26 64 99
13 66 80 27 83
14 20 98 51 91
15 21 61 100 40
16 76 16 27 40
17 66 65 97 92
18 81 52 9 5
19 65 75 1 15
20 50 78 44 16
5
1 12 2 4 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 17 18 20
2 10 3 6 7 8 9 14 16 17 18 20
3 14 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 18 20
4 10 1 3 4 6 10 11 14 15 17 18
5 11 2 3 5 6 8 12 13 15 17 19 20
18
1 34 22 97 8
2 92 69 58 58
3 53 80 90 88
4 57 46 12 64
5 38 53 74 84
6 98 62 12 92
7 90 57 53 81
8 14 46 8 7
9 14 34 3 4
10 100 81 92 12
11 49 74 60 34
12 7 9 91 71
13 7 84 52 64
14 95 51 17 63
15 28 73 61 70
16 23 99 35 68
17 1 87 93 89
18 69 36 40 84
5
1 13 2 3 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18
2 13 1 2 3 4 5 7 10 12 13 14 15 16 17
3 13 1 2 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18
4 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 16 18
5 15 1 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
9
1 25 90 56 50
2 69 54 71 17
3 18 60 17 35
4 92 43 10 59
5 99 34 4 61
6 12 15 95 88
7 48 22 64 71
8 10 93 6 9
9 29 24 20 13
3
1 7 1 3 5 6 7 8 9
2 3 2 5 6
3 6 2 3 4 5 6 7
10
1 34 62 37 22
2 81 95 18 23
3 29 81 69 13
4 58 4 34 46
5 99 10 82 24
6 56 79 72 43
7 27 61 8 27
8 36 16 85 15
9 96 29 55 74
10 85 53 8 72
2
1 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 7 2 4 5 6 7 9 10
18
1 81 12 5 98
2 84 35 56 93
3 87 96 56 44
4 34 86 13 30
5 64 6 25 95
6 42 52 84 10
7 67 36 49 81
8 23 35 41 74
9 90 58 26 45
10 77 16 11 34
11 48 17 17 67
12 27 33 80 81
13 17 27 38 56
14 53 20 94 73
15 19 67 11 94
16 47 100 87 3
17 97 75 96 64
18 25 94 12 7
3
1 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12 13 14 15 17
2 13 1 2 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15 16 17 18
3 11 1 2 4 5 6 7 10 11 16 17 18
10
1 65 95 31 38
2 63 55 26 66
3 93 60 41 39
4 91 29 74 91
5 90 22 88 80
6 53 60 17 41
7 43 41 42 38
8 20 4 79 83
9 27 5 58 61
10 74 86 5 35
3
1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10
2 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
3 7 1 3 4 5 8 9 10
10
1 31 20 7 54
2 51 53 41 53
3 34 29 58 70
4 93 65 52 55
5 2 38 25 18
6 26 96 100 35
7 54 84 98 78
8 44 95 70 38
9 29 35 99 77
10 60 76 16 39
5
1 4 4 6 7 10
2 7 1 2 3 5 7 8 10
3 6 3 4 5 6 7 9
4 6 1 2 3 4 5 6
5 7 1 2 4 5 7 9 10
17
1 6 44 60 33
2 32 29 92 45
3 23 36 66 44
4 46 29 7 94
5 66 83 21 12
6 57 36 84 13
7 91 27 48 86
8 17 22 12 84
9 15 37 16 71
10 2 96 65 7
11 24 10 100 31
12 70 82 42 7
13 27 31 69 14
14 89 36 92 4
15 75 63 68 91
16 1 44 31 79
17 5 21 64 46
3
1 13 1 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17
2 15 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 15 16 17
3 10 1 2 3 5 7 8 11 12 13 17
4
1 53 41 11 99
2 55 12 23 76
3 90 85 88 62
4 2 56 34 70
2
1 4 1 2 3 4
2 3 1 2 3
13
1 21 71 47 45
2 83 58 56 70
3 65 86 10 96
4 56 57 17 43
5 19 100 71 11
6 1 96 40 65
7 18 18 31 72
8 62 59 58 17
9 78 80 8 57
10 10 40 12 15
11 16 44 84 21
12 63 44 44 53
13 31 25 48 67
4
1 7 1 3 9 10 11 12 13
2 7 1 2 3 4 6 8 9
3 7 3 4 8 9 10 11 13
4 10 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 11 12 13
2
1 59 61 77 68
2 37 25 81 53
3
1 2 1 2
2 1 1
3 2 1 2
12
1 23 66 5 16
2 10 28 68 33
3 44 61 89 16
4 88 65 88 8
5 47 83 84 52
6 5 16 57 89
7 77 46 70 9
8 24 40 1 8
9 89 91 23 57
10 10 9 46 42
11 94 22 27 34
12 17 70 1 14
1
1 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
19
1 38 13 75 70
2 86 34 3 10
3 47 78 87 71
4 56 0 53 94
5 32 91 96 88
6 23 42 81 63
7 30 50 95 13
8 72 73 67 51
9 2 63 80 41
10 4 20 62 82
11 45 5 56 100
12 48 67 53 8
13 62 11 97 48
14 41 89 95 77
15 39 1 28 89
16 86 64 11 94
17 23 31 71 42
18 83 86 78 84
19 93 38 80 86
2
1 14 1 2 4 5 6 7 9 11 13 14 16 17 18 19
2 13 1 3 5 7 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 17 18
11
1 21 48 90 42
2 14 60 12 56
3 23 56 40 44
4 32 20 41 62
5 69 89 42 36
6 18 44 61 85
7 33 91 45 25
8 44 22 82 51
9 79 22 49 24
10 55 69 86 60
11 39 10 42 25
4
1 8 1 4 6 7 8 9 10 11
2 8 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 10
3 10 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
4 10 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 11
2
1 66 16 86 73
2 23 63 83 36
2
1 2 1 2
2 2 1 2
2
1 35 18 13 19
2 38 98 60 23
2
1 2 1 2
2 1 1
18
1 4 74 17 1
2 59 55 12 73
3 36 98 66 59
4 92 14 99 47
5 10 46 22 33
6 49 76 79 59
7 37 29 37 15
8 55 73 89 55
9 29 24 31 5
10 52 13 77 42
11 41 82 67 43
12 1 68 87 17
13 19 36 34 9
14 27 1 16 12
15 58 5 29 4
16 73 46 61 17
17 85 30 21 43
18 92 88 40 98
4
1 11 1 2 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 18
2 15 1 2 3 5 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18
3 9 2 4 6 8 11 12 13 14 16
4 13 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 17
18
1 21 52 32 4
2 85 32 58 17
3 68 70 52 90
4 46 45 82 77
5 84 51 49 3
6 89 24 53 80
7 99 67 85 42
8 52 91 98 49
9 98 74 78 30
10 77 9 24 36
11 4 0 28 27
12 64 13 97 10
13 76 35 88 45
14 34 20 54 40
15 38 78 24 38
16 2 88 28 21
17 45 6 65 58
18 15 18 34 89
1
1 18 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
8
1 29 9 39 28
2 53 71 95 76
3 67 8 27 21
4 73 49 72 72
5 5 77 66 45
6 95 75 37 98
7 70 21 29 71
8 75 45 68 47
1
1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
5
1 81 92 96 87
2 36 45 85 67
3 9 57 12 83
4 50 89 37 17
5 93 75 31 55
5
1 4 2 3 4 5
2 3 1 2 3
3 4 1 3 4 5
4 2 1 4
5 4 1 2 3 4
17
1 81 35 21 39
2 47 81 24 80
3 25 35 78 2
4 32 3 84 73
5 34 80 8 78
6 44 33 79 59
7 70 44 87 74
8 81 52 54 43
9 6 18 62 74
10 87 13 82 85
11 83 56 2 11
12 14 8 20 37
13 86 51 94 28
14 97 13 71 72
15 52 5 97 58
16 75 30 3 2
17 1 12 44 65
2
1 11 1 2 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14
2 15 1 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
14
1 56 44 45 15
2 65 68 48 41
3 55 77 30 7
4 67 89 18 62
5 4 23 39 94
6 93 37 6 35
7 79 36 89 60
8 97 21 61 30
9 97 10 87 5
10 44 40 1 86
11 96 7 93 82
12 56 93 28 10
13 52 70 79 66
14 48 18 80 37
3
1 5 6 8 9 11 13
2 8 1 3 4 5 7 9 10 12
3 8 1 2 6 7 10 12 13 14
13
1 10 66 20 29
2 25 8 82 74
3 7 92 74 33
4 3 19 22 85
5 17 46 54 55
6 9 72 88 85
7 8 100 90 98
8 47 74 6 67
9 51 8 20 26
10 37 18 34 53
11 44 2 98 60
12 78 20 9 71
13 99 25 28 15
5
1 7 2 4 6 7 9 11 12
2 9 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 11 13
3 8 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 12
4 11 1 2 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
5 11 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
16
1 18 5 97 5
2 63 11 47 25
3 52 48 54 13
4 84 69 43 46
5 28 32 94 37
6 63 6 79 35
7 10 26 6 81
8 4 25 55 99
9 27 3 76 3
10 35 51 1 23
11 4 98 11 6
12 42 48 20 54
13 100 20 72 14
14 82 87 72 2
15 75 39 88 77
16 49 64 80 95
2
1 14 1 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
2 11 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13
4
1 20 70 75 80
2 56 43 37 76
3 32 67 37 34
4 24 99 9 46
1
1 4 1 2 3 4
9
1 58 42 55 34
2 6 7 82 86
3 12 23 62 57
4 79 89 47 95
5 68 7 62 45
6 27 21 63 4
7 27 70 61 33
8 22 45 33 88
9 25 70 22 87
4
1 7 1 2 4 5 6 7 9
2 7 1 2 3 4 5 7 9
3 6 1 2 3 4 6 7
4 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
7
1 76 17 73 29
2 38 49 97 86
3 91 6 42 17
4 70 31 71 47
5 2 11 86 68
6 50 19 39 23
7 95 48 92 82
1
1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
7
1 37 25 19 99
2 17 7 68 26
3 33 2 8 90
4 44 68 96 29
5 24 86 85 9
6 10 100 5 100
7 91 5 15 15
5
1 4 2 4 5 6
2 5 1 3 4 6 7
3 4 2 3 5 7
4 6 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 3 1 3 5
19
1 41 66 46 98
2 89 58 70 100
3 1 7 54 55
4 7 25 30 10
5 98 18 48 3
6 14 43 79 94
7 93 5 40 15
8 23 32 28 25
9 25 91 57 26
10 33 98 55 79
11 69 33 4 8
12 87 30 45 33
13 38 10 32 92
14 77 14 58 63
15 74 32 64 49
16 17 31 84 92
17 70 7 62 92
18 75 84 6 16
19 45 82 39 61
3
1 15 1 2 3 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 15 16 17 18 19
2 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 17 18 19
3 14 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 18
16
1 19 100 99 70
2 28 76 45 64
3 95 2 6 21
4 91 31 73 65
5 28 43 87 78
6 40 26 48 46
7 72 31 43 81
8 42 52 31 73
9 44 39 28 29
10 45 88 49 72
11 23 96 64 7
12 17 91 87 88
13 71 36 7 26
14 87 25 55 6
15 70 59 31 97
16 42 10 16 61
4
1 15 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15 16
2 10 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 16
3 12 2 3 5 6 7 8 10 12 13 14 15 16
4 10 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 14
20
1 37 53 19 21
2 69 79 1 76
3 21 96 22 29
4 73 100 86 91
5 36 81 96 78
6 96 25 38 50
7 25 77 54 28
8 80 93 70 8
9 16 35 15 89
10 95 63 7 15
11 71 90 4 29
12 67 37 25 89
13 69 45 22 20
14 38 73 34 11
15 47 95 83 88
16 92 41 18 52
17 98 9 94 32
18 81 68 42 1
19 86 79 59 45
20 55 38 46 35
4
1 12 1 2 3 4 6 7 9 11 12 13 14 16
2 14 3 4 5 6 7 10 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
3 13 1 2 5 8 10 11 12 13 15 17 18 19 20
4 13 3 4 5 8 9 11 12 14 16 17 18 19 20
15
1 99 30 50 9
2 83 84 79 67
3 4 67 100 43
4 15 40 5 77
5 91 62 30 12
6 77 23 60 20
7 58 55 11 46
8 50 86 88 41
9 3 43 51 37
10 76 42 2 82
11 29 31 98 1
12 65 1 54 54
13 54 63 10 35
14 19 80 5 21
15 7 91 3 67
5
1 7 4 5 6 8 11 12 13
2 10 1 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 13 14
3 9 1 2 6 7 8 9 10 12 13
4 10 1 2 4 5 6 8 10 11 13 14
5 10 2 3 5 7 10 11 12 13 14 15
4
1 91 41 50 50
2 1 10 38 23
3 40 42 16 75
4 57 52 26 32
2
1 2 1 3
2 4 1 2 3 4
19
1 90 53 21 68
2 85 7 82 11
3 80 1 14 49
4 42 28 97 91
5 30 91 11 12
6 23 70 3 14
7 23 88 24 14
8 9 13 86 42
9 16 88 83 6
10 65 36 40 16
11 96 5 79 6
12 39 14 84 27
13 12 44 46 46
14 13 55 52 100
15 68 38 56 27
16 99 13 68 41
17 18 2 78 2
18 23 25 18 18
19 75 42 81 48
4
1 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 12 17 18
2 15 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 19
3 13 1 4 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18
4 11 1 3 8 9 11 13 15 16 17 18 19
17
1 34 28 53 99
2 20 7 52 48
3 26 37 58 61
4 16 5 3 96
5 39 6 88 16
6 41 4 83 29
7 15 98 1 34
8 17 25 90 19
9 94 97 58 94
10 74 43 3 61
11 8 95 29 13
12 47 40 40 31
13 7 29 20 27
14 87 6 62 54
15 32 91 59 62
16 94 82 96 48
17 66 79 2 6
4
1 10 2 3 4 6 8 11 12 13 14 17
2 11 1 3 4 5 7 11 12 13 14 16 17
3 12 1 2 3 5 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
4 11 1 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 14 15 17
6
1 6 4 62 76
2 45 66 100 99
3 82 6 68 94
4 12 65 54 69
5 47 56 19 89
6 41 51 71 99
2
1 6 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 6 1 2 3 4 5 6
12
1 17 36 75 58
2 23 88 21 74
3 14 13 95 14
4 43 97 50 6
5 29 0 22 37
6 84 23 24 31
7 81 2 65 62
8 21 42 51 11
9 51 26 54 78
10 40 14 75 27
11 27 73 63 22
12 1 2 67 13
4
1 6 1 4 5 9 10 12
2 7 3 4 7 8 9 10 12
3 10 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 10 11 12
4 9 1 2 3 4 6 8 9 10 12
15
1 43 5 85 72
2 16 60 63 26
3 94 79 31 28
4 80 72 88 38
5 39 64 60 37
6 39 78 54 46
7 52 8 10 9
8 23 21 66 51
9 79 24 81 2
10 22 82 53 43
11 21 15 69 84
12 93 49 80 56
13 36 36 4 39
14 18 69 59 58
15 71 86 8 21
5
1 13 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 14 15
2 10 2 3 4 6 7 8 10 13 14 15
3 8 1 2 4 5 7 8 10 13
4 11 1 2 4 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15
5 8 2 3 4 5 8 9 13 14
5
1 30 87 16 19
2 65 9 89 75
3 6 23 2 81
4 85 90 39 17
5 67 70 76 27
4
1 3 1 2 5
2 4 1 2 3 5
3 5 1 2 3 4 5
4 3 3 4 5
9
1 50 44 68 1
2 58 33 83 42
3 42 8 36 3
4 21 22 53 17
5 13 7 59 17
6 23 95 26 57
7 47 15 54 98
8 20 84 26 20
9 35 4 1 93
5
1 5 4 5 6 8 9
2 7 1 3 4 5 6 8 9
3 5 1 4 5 8 9
4 6 1 2 3 4 7 8
5 5 1 3 6 7 9
15
1 40 34 66 80
2 99 40 34 91
3 51 8 31 5
4 100 8 1 87
5 49 50 7 9
6 68 83 100 96
7 46 92 86 64
8 32 36 23 100
9 31 46 86 88
10 28 85 94 71
11 63 1 29 77
12 38 98 36 29
13 89 54 98 94
14 13 85 88 50
15 24 19 54 73
2
1 13 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 15
2 10 3 4 5 6 7 9 11 13 14 15
13
1 30 23 71 65
2 64 69 7 40
3 95 28 58 44
4 64 16 52 58
5 93 91 83 74
6 91 14 8 27
7 45 60 92 20
8 97 22 97 81
9 58 30 26 19
10 27 35 60 84
11 27 32 19 70
12 95 60 53 70
13 13 17 92 35
1
1 13 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
8
1 53 32 77 26
2 88 20 92 31
3 74 14 21 59
4 44 15 64 19
5 1 66 89 96
6 17 8 33 90
7 40 27 67 16
8 83 12 60 6
1
1 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2
1 13 42 53 97
2 59 21 3 68
3
1 1 2
2 1 2
3 2 1 2
16
1 45 48 3 32
2 77 89 56 22
3 81 16 67 76
4 5 88 90 3
5 71 77 7 1
6 71 37 5 75
7 19 95 56 84
8 20 16 86 89
9 61 75 51 40
10 86 19 22 58
11 42 26 14 40
12 3 43 13 3
13 46 59 61 71
14 100 55 52 17
15 47 80 54 59
16 83 18 55 91
3
1 11 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 15 16
2 12 2 3 5 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
3 14 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
8
1 42 95 98 64
2 20 41 50 7
3 69 19 71 11
4 49 33 78 51
5 75 50 21 32
6 50 38 62 15
7 84 18 52 41
8 41 10 4 77
4
1 5 1 2 3 5 7
2 4 1 2 3 7
3 4 1 2 6 8
4 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
11
1 95 99 35 69
2 10 94 89 22
3 23 82 43 38
4 91 77 79 21
5 22 0 14 45
6 8 73 37 62
7 59 37 29 42
8 65 49 32 97
9 39 3 20 66
10 97 67 56 60
11 70 76 66 98
2
1 8 1 2 6 7 8 9 10 11
2 9 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 11
18
1 76 46 43 34
2 27 33 12 51
3 40 63 66 56
4 48 2 60 1
5 42 13 10 75
6 55 90 53 73
7 59 32 3 26
8 9 21 5 76
9 98 73 77 48
10 43 76 83 88
11 100 97 58 100
12 96 61 30 69
13 12 15 52 39
14 82 93 11 5
15 93 86 80 66
16 32 55 39 85
17 55 38 37 16
18 70 68 4 19
4
1 14 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 16 17
2 9 1 3 6 8 9 12 15 17 18
3 8 1 2 3 6 10 12 13 16
4 12 1 2 3 4 6 7 10 11 13 14 15 17
2
1 27 94 1 29
2 29 10 83 5
2
1 2 1 2
2 2 1 2
9
1 86 75 7 18
2 65 60 4 32
3 17 18 55 14
4 60 5 69 57
5 31 93 26 47
6 6 21 16 54
7 18 0 46 49
8 52 58 74 35
9 12 51 30 81
3
1 7 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 5 2 3 4 7 9
3 6 1 2 3 4 6 9
8
1 77 2 57 80
2 63 10 51 25
3 87 84 4 21
4 55 25 16 87
5 48 12 95 86
6 90 68 35 79
7 7 25 71 14
8 29 74 92 98
5
1 5 1 2 3 4 7
2 7 1 2 3 4 5 7 8
3 7 1 2 3 5 6 7 8
4 6 2 4 5 6 7 8
5 4 1 3 5 7
7
1 61 95 13 17
2 81 82 93 97
3 41 65 11 6
4 68 72 35 39
5 41 19 79 13
6 66 82 100 96
7 62 44 53 13
2
1 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
18
1 18 70 60 66
2 15 95 64 26
3 35 57 33 72
4 64 100 14 82
5 67 65 1 95
6 21 1 90 100
7 82 93 43 92
8 70 100 14 53
9 2 28 73 25
10 12 96 82 89
11 95 55 32 14
12 92 28 87 97
13 38 100 18 87
14 3 76 83 60
15 78 21 77 25
16 14 91 54 90
17 15 44 38 27
18 84 82 84 19
5
1 10 1 5 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
2 10 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 13 15
3 15 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
4 11 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 16 17
5 9 1 4 6 8 9 11 13 15 16
11
1 64 75 81 28
2 27 63 41 3
3 49 100 68 40
4 67 86 62 82
5 21 54 48 100
6 35 47 8 97
7 36 7 43 38
8 51 67 11 72
9 97 80 41 43
10 73 33 28 33
11 28 50 82 95
3
1 7 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 8 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
3 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
7
1 72 77 28 11
2 72 52 37 37
3 37 93 47 27
4 24 98 50 13
5 69 66 6 53
6 43 30 100 9
7 58 37 34 61
5
1 4 1 2 3 4
2 5 1 3 4 5 6
3 3 1 2 7
4 6 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 4 2 3 5 6
12
1 26 86 10 14
2 19 24 17 56
3 51 11 8 92
4 66 33 11 89
5 7 61 94 69
6 76 91 55 93
7 78 8 22 34
8 21 18 20 56
9 37 25 25 82
10 33 37 34 42
11 34 36 21 94
12 100 95 92 32
1
1 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
3
1 41 49 91 90
2 57 58 72 28
3 34 63 2 36
5
1 1 2
2 3 1 2 3
3 2 2 3
4 3 1 2 3
5 2 2 3
3
1 26 8 89 73
2 59 73 91 2
3 77 96 58 51
4
1 3 1 2 3
2 1 3
3 2 2 3
4 3 1 2 3
20
1 9 84 8 67
2 69 71 11 59
3 78 32 40 89
4 79 53 65 34
5 87 89 24 38
6 14 47 13 78
7 2 49 9 92
8 35 76 53 17
9 70 96 6 12
10 56 41 6 68
11 31 59 26 45
12 80 79 95 91
13 48 9 52 70
14 7 26 87 16
15 64 55 83 47
16 98 48 61 87
17 86 38 45 18
18 99 30 57 3
19 25 48 78 35
20 93 5 42 72
3
1 10 3 5 7 8 9 12 13 14 17 19
2 15 1 2 3 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 15 16 17 19 20
3 16 1 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
0
```